# NodeJS mssql library insert weird special characters to database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I try to insert records into my table using mssql from nodeJS. My param `product_code = "0123456789"` is a string. I checked it before insert to the table, but after run the query, the record appear in the database is "?0123456789" if I format that field as varchar(30). If I re-format it as nvarchar(30), it will appear as "ÿ0123456789".
I don't know why it happen only for this parameter.
I tried to figure out 3 causes:

1. My code problem: I use vim on a tmux session. I tried to list all hidden character using `set list; set listchars=tab:→\ ,nbsp:␣,trail:•,eol:¶,precedes:«,extends:»`  but see nothing strange
2. My database server problem: This problem never happened before, I have no idea with the database server and have no expertise to figure out what happen with it. We use remote database server and it's running Microsoft SQL on Windows server. If you have some clue, please suggest me some keywords to google it.
3. My network problem: is it possible that my Debian 10 OS has virus? I `ssh` to my backend server and start tmux session, and run vim as text editor. I use this method for thousands of hour but I experience this problem the first time.

````
let pool;

exports.DB = MSSQL;

exports.init = async function(){
    const DB_HOST = process.env.DB_HOST;
    const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER;
    const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS;
    const DB_DATABASE = process.env.DB_DATABASE;

    const config = {
        user: DB_USER,
        password: DB_PASS,
        server: DB_HOST,
        database: DB_DATABASE,
        options: {
            //encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
        }
    }
    
    console.log("DATABASE:");
    console.log("Host: " + DB_HOST);
    console.log("User: " + DB_USER);
    console.log("Database: " + DB_DATABASE);

    try{
        pool = await MSSQL.connect(config);
    }catch(error){
        console.log("DATABASE: Failed to connect to SQL Server");
    }

    if(pool){
        console.log("DATABASE: Connected");
    }
}

exports.getPool = function(){
    return pool;
}

myFunct = async function(product_code, other_param){
    try {
    console.log("product_code");
    console.log(typeof product_code);
    console.log(product_code);

        const pool = MSSQL.getPool();
        await pool.request().input('other_field', other_param).input('product_code', product_code).query("INSERT INTO my_database_table (product_code, other_field) VALUES(@product_code, @other_field);");

        return {
            result: true
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.trace(error);
        console.log("myFunct: " + error);
        return {
            result: false,
            error: ERROR.SYSTEM
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Where is `product_code` come from? Print out more information about it, `console.log(product_code.length);`, `console.log(product_code.charCodeAt(0));`

Comment: If product_code is received as the first field in a character stream I'd check whatever is encoding that stream - probably it is sending it in UTF-8 encoding with a BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Comment: thanks, I got `product_code.length=13` and `product_code.charCodeAt(0)=65279`.
I got the `product_code` from `req.body.product_code`.

Comment: Thank you all in advanced.
A lot of thank to @hoangdv. I fixed my code and add validator. My `product_code` should only contains number, so I added `product_code.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")`.
@AlwaysLearning yeah, it was in coded as UTF-8. Right now I trimmed `product_code`, so no more weird character appears.